# MVC EditorTemplate for list that is not part of the model

Tags: model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates, editortemplates

Within my view I call a partialview for a List. In that partial view I seperate that list into two IEnumerables and for each list I want to call the EditorTemplate for ModelType:

My PartialView:

```
@model List<ModelType>

@using System.Collections;         

@{
    int countModelTypeLeft = (Model.Count % 2 != 0) ? Model.Count + 1 : Model.Count ;
    int countModelTypeRight = Model.Count;

    IEnumerable<ModelType> modelTypeListLeft = Model.Take(countModelTypeLeft);
    IEnumerable<ModelType> modelTypeListRight = Model.Range(countModelTypeLeft , countModelTypeRight );
}
    <div class="modeltype-left" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        // How can I call EditorFor for modelTypeListLeft  now?
    </div>

    <div class="modeltype-right" style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        // How can I call EditorFor for modelTypeListRight  now?
    </div>
```

As you can see, I am stuck because I can't call EditorFor because the two Lists modelTypeListLeft  and countModelTypeRight  are not part of the given Model in the partial view. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a editor template for ModelType, then this will still work and use the correct editor template

```
<div class="modeltype-left" style="float: left; width: 50%;">        
    @foreach(var leftItem in modelTypeListLeft )
    {
        Html.EditorFor(m=>leftItem)
    }
</div>

<div class="modeltype-right" style="float: right; width: 50%;">        
    @foreach(var rightItem in modelTypeListRight)
    {
        Html.EditorFor(m=>rightItem)
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to take adavantage of the fact calling `@Html.EditorFor` with an IEnumberable makes MVC choosing the correct EditorTemplate for the given Model. But your answer gave me the right hint: `@Html.EditorFor(model => modelTypeListLeft )` calls the EditorTemplate for every item in the list!
But anyway I didn't know that the parameter expression in MVC always means that I have to give a part of the given model but you just proved that this is not the case. How can I learn more about expression?

Comment: :), Not sure what resources I can point you to... writing more code definately helps ;)

Comment: if the answer made any sense can you mark it as an answer please.(:P Greedy)